# Don't understand function List_list in the CII book, page 108

Tags: c

```
typedef struct T *T;
struct T {
    T rest;
    void *first;
}

T List_list(void *x, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    T list, *p = &list;
    va_start(ap, x);

    for ( ; x; x = va_arg(ap, void *)) {
        NEW(*p);
        (*p)->first = x;
        p = &(*p)->rest;
    }
    *p = NULL;
    va_end(ap);
    return list;
}
```

I have several questions for this function.

- Why allocate a `new *p` in the for loop? `*p` is assigned `&list`, if a new memory is allocated to `*p`, is `*p` still have the address of list?
- What does `p = &(*p)->rest` mean? `*p` is `&list`, so is `&(*p)` the address of the pointer to list? If so, should it be `p = *(&(*p))->rest` ?

Here is the definition of NEW

```
#define NEW(p) ((p) = ALLOC((long)sizeof *(p)))
#define ALLOC(nbytes) Mem_alloc((nbytes), __FILE__, __LINE__)
void *Mem_alloc(long nbytes, const char *file, int line){
    void *ptr;
    assert(nbytes > 0);
    ptr = malloc(nbytes);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        ¢raise Mem_Failed 742
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that defines `NEW`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line `typedef struct T *T;` defines `T` as a pointer to a `struct T`, so `T *p` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct T`.

- a `NEW(*p)` is a new list item, one is allocated for each argument
- `p = &(*p)->rest` is moving the 'insert position' `p` to the next location. After this line `p` points to the `rest` pointer of the last item in the list. It could also be written as `p = &((*p)->rest)` to clarify the precedence.

Comment: Is `p=&((*p)->rest)` same as `*p = *p->rest` ?

Comment: @yuchen no, not at all.

Comment: No, `*p = *p->rest` would result in undefined behavior, because p is pointing to a uninitialized pointer. `*p` is `list` first, and later (in the loop) the `rest` of the last item.